# Assertion on 'task' failed: Must inherit from class 'Task', but has class 'data.frame'

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost, mlr

I trained an XGBoost model using mlr package. I need to make a prediction on a test set that does not have the target variable. I should just predict the target variable. If I do this:

```
testF.pred <- predict(xgmodel,X_test)
```

The error is:

```
Error in predict.WrappedModel(xgmodel, X_test) : 
Assertion on 'task' failed: Must inherit from class 'Task', but has class 'data.frame'.
```

I should define a task to predict the target variable. However, If I want to create a task,

```
mytest_task <- makeClassifTask(data = X_test)
testF.pred <- predict(xgmodel,mytest_task)
```

The error is:

```
Error in assertString(target) : 
  argument "target" is missing, with no default
```

How I should make a task to do prediction on a dataset without the target variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `newdata` argument for this, i.e.

```
predict(xgmodel, newdata = X_test)
```

See [the help page](https://rdrr.io/github/mlr-org/mlr/man/predict.WrappedModel.html) for more information.

On a separate note, I recommend switching to [mlr3](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/basics.html#sec-predicting), the successor of mlr.